# Is it wrong to update the vuex module state using actions and mutations in this way?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuex-modules, vuex4

I have a question about actions and mutations.

I have a backend with a web API with the following routes: getProducts (which returns all products) and addProduct, deleteProduct, updateProduct which returns only success or fail.

In the frontend, in the specific module state, I am interested in keeping a list of all products.

**state.js:**

```
export default () => ({
    products: [],
});
```

How wrong is the next approach?

Instead of committing mutations on addProduct (push a new product to the state), updateProduct (edit the state) and deleteProduct (splice the state) actions, I “refresh” my state with what I already have added/updated/deleted in the database, dispatching the getProducts action, which is the only one that commits a mutation.

In this way my state is always up to date with the “one single source of truth” (database data), and I also maintain the state up to date on concurrent tabs/computers/browsers requests.

**actions.js:**

```
  getProducts({commit}) {
        const route = `products/todo`;
        return axios.get(route)
            .then(response => {
                commit('SET_PRODUCTS', response.data);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                //....
            })
    },

    addProduct({dispatch}, data) {
        const route = `products/todo`;
        return axios.post(route, data)
            .then((response) => {
                return dispatch('getProducts').then(() => {
                    //....
                })
            })
            .catch(err => {
               //...
            })

    },

    deleteProduct({dispatch}, data) {
        const route = `products/todo`;
        return axios.delete(route)
            .then(() => {
                return dispatch('getProducts').then(() => {
                  //..........
                })
            })
            .catch(err => {
                //......
            })
    },

    updateProduct({dispatch}, data) {
        const route = `products/todo`;
        return axios.put(route, data)
            .then(response => {
                return dispatch('getProducts').then(() => {
                  //...
                })
            })
            .catch(err => {
                //...
            })
    },
      
//mutations.js

export default {
    SET_PRODUCTS: (state, data) => {
        state.products = data;
    },
}
```

Is this a wrong approach? Do I incorrectly use the state management with VUEX if I choose to write the actions and the mutations like that?

Comment: It's fine and good.  You might be making 2 http requests where only 1 is needed.  It may make sense for each of the other verbs to return the results so you wouldn't have to call `getProducts` when they complete

Comment: Great then! Thanks for your answer!